# Remaking jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to remake a jQuery script by (http://jorenrapini.com/blog/javascript/the-simple-quick-and-small-jquery-html-form-validation-solution). This script is checking if a from is filled, if not a error message will appear.

What I want to do is to only get the error message when one of two form input-fields are filled out, if none of them are then they should be ignored. The form fields are named "firstinput" and "secondinput" (you can see their id in the code).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["firstinput", "secondinput"];
    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";

    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

    $("#theform").submit(function(){    
        //Validate required fields
        for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
            var input = $('#'+required[i]);
            if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                input.addClass("needsfilled");
                input.val(emptyerror);
                errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            } else {
                input.removeClass("needsfilled");
            }
        }

        // Validate the e-mail.
        if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("needsfilled");
            email.val(emailerror);
        }

        //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
        if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            errornotice.hide();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
    $(":input").focus(function(){       
       if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
       }
    });
});
```

Can anybody please help me with a solution, I would really appreciate it. 
/A girl that spend a LOT of time solving this without luck :(

Comment: Where's the code that's supposed to check if both of the fields are empty?

Comment: Nowhere, because nothing like that is implemented, yet. Do you want to help me with that, sir?

Comment: You should try to implement it yourself, TNCodeMonkey provided you with some code. Of course we could do it all for you, but then you'd learn absolutely nothing. And the point of SO is for you to learn, not for us to do your work for you. Now, if you try, and still can't get it to work, _then_ post a question and we can help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap your for loop in a conditional that evaluates if one or the other has a value.

```
if($("#field1").val() == "" && $("#field2").val() == ""){
//Ignore
}else{
//Do something
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["firstinput", "secondinput"];
    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";

    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

    $("#theform").submit(function(){    
        //Validate required fields
      if($("#firstinput").val() != "" || $("#secondinput").val() != "")
      {
        for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
            var input = $('#'+required[i]);
            if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                input.addClass("needsfilled");
                input.val(emptyerror);
                errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            } else {
                input.removeClass("needsfilled");
            }
        }
      }
        // Validate the e-mail.
        if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("needsfilled");
            email.val(emailerror);
        }

        //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
        if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            errornotice.hide();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
    $(":input").focus(function(){       
       if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer TNCodeMonkey, the truth is that I don't know how to make this work. I would need somebody that could show me a working example.